# Parsing issue c++

Tags: c++, oop

Im trying to convert from java to c++ and i got this problem when i want to create an object like the following:

Hero.cpp file:

```
#include "Hero.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Enemy.h"

using namespace std;

Hero::Hero()
{
    level = 1;
    exp = 0;
    life = 100*level;
    dmg = 10*level;
}

void Hero::Attack(Enemy ene){
    ene.loseHealth(dmg);
}

void Hero::Heal(){
    life += 50;
}

void Hero::loseHealth(int x){
    life -= x;
}

void Hero::receiveExp(){
    exp += 10;
    cout<<"Your hero is now level: "<< getLevel() << endl;

}

int Hero::getLevel(){
    if(exp >= 10 && exp <= 19){
        level = 2;
    }else if(exp >= 20 && exp <= 29){
        level = 3;
    }else if(exp >= 30 && exp <= 39){
        level = 4;
    }else if(exp >= 40){
        level = 5;
    }else{
        level = 1;
    }
    return level;
}
//Get all information about the hero
void Hero::printStatus(){
    cout<<"Your level: " << level<<endl;
    cout<<"Current exp: " << exp<<endl;
    cout<<"Amount of HP: " << life << endl;
    cout<<"DMG: " << dmg << endl;
}
```

the thing is when i try to compile it says Parsing issue to following:

```
void Hero::Attack(Enemy ene){
        ene.loseHealth(dmg);
    }
```

Got a Enemy class too that nearly looks the same coming with the same Parsing issue at its Attack function.

Im using XCode5.
It says: "Unknown type name 'Enemy'"
to this one:

```
void Attack(Enemy ene);
```

Hero.h file:

```
#ifndef __ConsoleGame__Hero__
#define __ConsoleGame__Hero__

#include <iostream>
#include "Enemy.h"
#include <cstdlib>

class Hero{
public:
    Hero();
    void Attack(Enemy ene);
    void Heal();
    void loseHealth(int x);
    void receiveExp();
    int getLevel();
    void printStatus();

private:
    int life;
    int dmg;
    int exp;
    int level;

};

#endif /* defined(__ConsoleGame__Hero__) */
```

My Enemy.h file:

```
#ifndef __ConsoleGame__Enemy__
#define __ConsoleGame__Enemy__

#include <iostream>
#include "Hero.h"
#include <cstdlib>

class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy();
    void Attack(Hero h);
    void Heal();
    void loseHealth(int x);
    void setDmg(int x);
    int getHealth();

private:
    int life;
    int dmg;
    int level;

};

#endif /* defined(__ConsoleGame__Enemy__) */
```

My Enemy.cpp file:

```
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Hero.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

Enemy::Enemy()
{
    life = 50 * (rand()% 6);
    dmg = 5 * (rand()%6);
    level = rand()% 6;
}

//Attack
void Enemy::Attack(Hero h){
    h.loseHealth(dmg);
}

//Lose health
void Enemy::loseHealth(int x){
    life -= x;
}

//Heal
void Enemy::Heal(){
    life+= 10;
}

//Amount of hp
int Enemy::getHealth(){
    return life;
}

//Set dmg
void Enemy::setDmg(int x){
    dmg = x;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: _'the thing is when i try to compile it says Parsing issue to following'_ _Parsing issue_ isn't something that can be understood by means of any c++ standards for any readers here. What exactly happens please??

Comment: whats in enemy.h? It looks like you may have a circular dependency and instead of #including "enemy.h" you may just want to forward declare `class Enemy;`

Comment: Possible that you can give my an example on that?

Comment: Not related to your current problem, but may save you one in the future.  You'll want to pass references to things like `void Hero::Attack(Enemy ene)` otherwise you're modifying a temporary copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have here is circular inclusion, hero.h including enemy.h and enemy.h including hero.h. This tends to show up as one of the types can't be found.

The usual way to solve this is to forward declare the class and only take a reference instead of an object.

hero.h:

```
 class Enemy;
 class Hero {
     void Attack(Enemy& e);
 };
```

hero.cpp:

```
#include "hero.h"
#include "enemy.h"

void Hero::Attack(Enemy& e) { ... }
```

enemy.h:

```
 class Hero;
 class Enemy {
     void Attack(Hero& e);
 };
```

enemy.cpp:

```
#include "enemy.h"
#include "hero.h"

void Enemy::Attack(Hero& e) { ... }
```

In general you want to forward declare as much as possible to reduce header dependencies, which can lead to quickly increasing compile times. One small modification means rebuilding half the project.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using "include guards":

```
#ifndef __ConsoleGame__Hero__
#define __ConsoleGame__Hero__
```

It's easy to make a copy and paste error and forget to change them in another file.
Make sure your symbols (**ConsoleGame__Hero**) are different in all your class include files.

Answer (score 0):

You have a looped include - you include `enemy.h` and `hero.h` with eachother - include it only in one place.

Comment: Can you tell me how my two Attack() functions can work then?

Comment: @dutt has an answer for You

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
#pragma once
```

instead of that defines...

And make one common.h header file with all includes :)

You are cross including and that is the bad.

Comment: Nothing says "thanks" like a like :D

Comment: Sorry cant do that yet xD

Answer (score 0):

In C++, this

```
void Hero::Attack(Enemy ene){
    ene.loseHealth(dmg);
}
```

will not do what you expect. It should be

```
void Hero::Attack(Enemy *ene){
    ene->loseHealth(dmg);
}
```

or even better, as proposed in another answer:

```
void Hero::Attack(Enemy& ene){
    ene.loseHealth(dmg);
}
```

because with the first version, there is a copy of `ene` made, so the enemy is never losing health, just the copy of it does.
Then you don't need to include the files in each other, you can make forward declarations:

```
class Enemy;
```

in Hero.h and vice-versa.